# Disable Excel Debug/End popup or Read excel variable from c# project

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a C# Interop method that opens an excel file, runs a macro, saves and closes it.

```
    private void DoExcelMacro(string fileName, string macroName)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook;
        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

        excel.Run(macroName);
        Worksheet ws = workbook.ActiveSheet;

        workbook.SaveAs(fileName);
        excel.DisplayAlerts = true;

        ws = null;
        workbook.Close();
        workbook = null;
        excel = null;

        GC.Collect();
    }
```

It works great unless there is an error in the macro like:

```
    Public Sub MacroEntry()
    Dim test AS Integer
        test = "A"
    End Sub
```

Turning off `DisplayAlerts` doesn't work. If I click "End" on the popup, I receive the error in my C# app.

**Question 1:** Is there a way to suppress the error popup but let the error fall through to the C# app?

Or

I can modify the Excel macro to catch the error

```
    Public macroError As ErrObject

    Public Sub MacroEntry()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim test As Integer
        test = "A"

    ErrorHandler:
        Set macroError = Err
        Exit Sub
    End Sub
```

**Question 2:** How could I read the Excel variable `macroError` from the C# Interop object?

I would prefer the solution to Question 1 if it is possible.

Comment: From what I've read, exiting the macro is the best you can hope for. You could do something really weird like have the error handler write data to the workbook somewhere and check after the macro runs. I feel so guilty for saying that. It's just wrong.

Comment: I hear you. I thought the same thing and it just isn't something I want to do LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a macro that normally is a Sub(void returning) then change to a Function(happy-path returns a string of ""), but with catching the error, you can check in C# for a non-empty String.

```
Public Function MacroEntry() As String
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim test As Integer
    test = "A"

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    MacroEntry= Err.Description
    Exit Function
End Function
```

**C#:**

```
string macroErrorReturn = excel.Run(macroName).ToString();
if (macroErrorReturn != "") {
    //error occurred in macro   
}
```